# Pivot Chart Title to Display Multiple Selected Items

Tags: excel, vba

I have a pivotchart that when the selected filter (work center) is changed, it updates the chart title to display that work center name.  However, if I check the box to allow multiple selections, the chart title simply shows "All" instead of showing each of the actual selected items.  I haven't found a way to get it to show what I'm looking for.  Below is the code that I'm using to update the chart title as well as the code for the filter change event that fires it off

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.Run "'Prod_Tools.xlam'!gPTWCChange", Target.PivotFields("WorkCenter").CurrentPage
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub


Sub gPTWCChange(ByVal WC As String)
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim CPWB1 As Workbook
    For Each wb1 In Workbooks
        If InStr(1, wb1.Name, "Capacity Planning Rep", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Set CPWB1 = Workbooks(wb1.Name)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wb1
    On Error Resume Next
    CPWB1.Charts("Workcenter By Week").ChartTitle.Text = "Work Center: " & WC
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

What I would like is when multiple items are selected, have the chart title look like "Data for: Workcenter_A, Workcenter_B, Workcenter_F"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your adapted sub. Notice that its parameter has changed.

```
Public Sub gPTWCChange(ByVal pfWC As Excel.PivotField)
    Const sSEPARATOR As String = ", "

    Dim sChartTitle As String
    Dim oPivotItem As Excel.PivotItem
    Dim lVisibleCount As Long

    '... Your original code ...
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim CPWB1 As Workbook
    For Each wb1 In Workbooks
        If InStr(1, wb1.Name, "Capacity Planning Rep", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Set CPWB1 = Workbooks(wb1.Name)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wb1

    '... New code to compute the chart title ...        
    If pfWC.EnableMultiplePageItems Then
        'Build the chart title from the visible items in the PivotField.
        lVisibleCount = 0
        For Each oPivotItem In pfWC.PivotItems
            If oPivotItem.Visible Then
                lVisibleCount = lVisibleCount + 1
                sChartTitle = sChartTitle & sSEPARATOR & oPivotItem.Caption
            End If
        Next

        'Drop the leading separator.
        sChartTitle = Mid$(sChartTitle, Len(sSEPARATOR) + 1)

        'Manage plural.
        sChartTitle = "Work Center" & IIf(lVisibleCount > 1, "s", "") & ": " & sChartTitle
    Else
        sChartTitle = "Work Center: " & pfWC.CurrentPage
    End If

    '... Your original code ...
    On Error Resume Next        
    CPWB1.Charts("Workcenter By Week").ChartTitle.Text = sChartTitle
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

And call your sub as follows:

```
Application.Run "'Prod_Tools.xlam'!gPTWCChange", Target.PivotFields("WorkCenter")
```

The principle is to send your sub a reference to the PivotField object, and from there, check its `EnableMultiplePageItems` property.

Comment: Thanks so much.  That is exactly what I was looking for and just couldn't figure out :)